# Intuitively, what is the source term of the Einstein field equation?

Tags: general-relativity

My copy of Feynman's "Six Not-So-Easy Pieces" has an interesting introduction by Roger Penrose. In that introduction (copyright 1997 according to the copyright page), Penrose complains that Feynman's "simplified account of the Einstein field equation of general relativity did need a qualification that he did not quite give." Feynman's intuitive discussion rests on relating the "radius excess" to a constant times the gravitational mass $M$: for a sphere of measured radius $r_{\mathrm{meas}}$ and surface area $A$ enclosing matter with average mass density $\rho$ smoothly distributed throughout the sphere,

$$
\sqrt{\frac{A}{4\pi}} - r_{\mathrm{meas}} = \frac{G}{3c^2}\cdot M,
$$

wherein $G$ is Newton's gravitational constant, $c$ is the speed of light in vacuum, and $M=4\pi\rho r^3/3$. I don't know what $r$ is supposed to be, but it's presumably $\sqrt{\frac{A}{4\pi}}$. Feynman gratifyingly points out that $\frac{G}{3c^2} \approx 2.5\times 10^{-28}$ meters per kilogram (for Earth, this corresponds to a radius excess of about 1.5 mm). Feynman is also careful to point out that this is a statement about *average* curvature.

Penrose's criticism is: "the "active" mass which is the source of gravity is not simply the same as the energy (according to Einstein's $E=mc^2$); instead, this source is the energy *plus the sum of the pressures*". Damned if I know what that means -- whose pressure on what?

So my question is, taking into account Penrose's criticism but maintaining Feynman's intuitive style, what's $M$? I only care about average curvature, so please try not to muddy my head with the full Einstein equation. I have a copy of Wald too.

Comment: Here's a concrete example. Inside an atomic nucleus, we have a typical pressure $P$ due to electromagnetic repulsion of $\sim10^{33}$ Pa. The nuclear mass density $\rho$ is $\sim 10^{18}$ kg/m3. In natural units where c=1, $P$ and $\rho$ have the same units, and $P/\rho\sim10^{-2}$. This leads to testable predictions if you test the gravitational interactions of substances that have different values of $P/\rho$: Kreuzer, Phys. Rev. 169 (1968) 1007. For a simplified description: http://www.lightandmatter.com/html_books/genrel/ch08/ch08.html#Section8.1

Comment: now cross-listed at TP.SE: http://theoreticalphysics.stackexchange.com/q/849/189